# Best 'init' method to set variable value for iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm still fairly new to Objective C so please bear with me:

My app has a Delegate, a Navigation Controller, and a View.
I also use a Singleton for "global" variables.

I know I can do this but it seems ungainly:

```
#import "GlobalData.h"
@synthesize ...
NSInteger junk;
NSInteger moreJunk;

-(void)myMethod{
   GlobalData *globDat=[GlobalData getSingleton];
   junk=globDat.someValue;
}

-(void)myOtherMethod{
   GlobalData *globDat=[GlobalData getSingleton];
   moreJunk=globDat.someOtherValue;
}
```

I'd like to this but it can't:

```
#import  "GlobalData.h"
@synthesize ...
NSInteger junk;
NSInteger moreJunk;
GlobalData *globDat=[GlobalData getSingleton]; //Compiler won't allow this line

-(void)myMethod{
    junk=globDat.someValue;
}

-(void)myOtherMethod{
    moreJunk=globDat.someOtherValue;
}
```

However I can do this:

```
#import  "GlobalData.h"
@synthesize ...
NSInteger junk;
NSInteger moreJunk;
GlobalData *globDat;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        globDat=[GlobalData getSingleton];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)myMethod{
    junk=globDat.someValue;
}

-(void)myOtherMethod{
    moreJunk=globDat.someOtherValue;
}
```

So, is there a standard/common/proper "init" method to use for all Classes?

Should I just do this in every Class?

```
-(id)init{
    if(self=[super init]){
        globDat=[GlobalData getSingleton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: @PiotrPawełDębosz no, there's still reasons to use `@synthesize`. For example, if you have a readonly property, and need a custom getter, you can still have it generate an iVar for you using `@synthesize`, and if you ever want to change the name of the generated ivar, you must use `@synthesize`.

Comment: @PiotrPawełDębosz I mis-typed, I meant getter. And, there are times when you don't want a getter to be made at all, especially if you're messing around with KVC. Also, my point about ivar names still remains. Some of us use a different convention for our variables.

Comment: Sorry - I was unclear - the @synthesize was just a pseudo-code placeholder and not directly related to the Singleton.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you will use `GlobalData`.

## extensive use in many methods

If you plan to make an extensive use of `GlobalData` in your class (in many methods), then, you should better add
`@propertu (nonatomic, readwrite, weak)GlobalData *globalData` in your `.h`
(or, better, in the class extension). In your main `init...` method, you set the value `self.globalData = [GlobalData getSingleton];`. You can also do as you did, with an instance variable, `GlobalData* myGlobalData` in your `.h` or in the class extension.

Make sure your `init...` method starts with `init` and make sure there is a "main" `init...` method (we call it the "designated initializer"). You can simply override the `init` method of `NSObject`. But, if you need, you can define

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)str
{
    self = [super init] ; // or another one ; here you should use the designated init. of the parent class

    if (self){
        self.string = str ;
        self.globalData = [GlobalData getSingleton] ; 
    }

    return self;
}
```

## extensive use in few methods

If you intensively use `GlobalData` in one or two methods, you don't need to do so. You will just define a local variable `GlobalData * globalData = [GlobalData getSingleton];` and use it.

The third code you propose is not objected-oriented.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work, but I still need to address the 'init' question - should I be using a 'standard' init method like the one I posted in all my Classes?

Comment: I answered my own question but it may be exactly as you proposed - let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can do this but it seems ungainly...

You seem to be asking how to do away with the part where you retrieve the value you want from your singleton. The best way to do that is to eliminate the singleton in the first place.

You say that you have an app delegate, a navigation controller, and a view. You probably also have a view controller. If those are the main objects in your application, you might consider storing your data in your view controller. Or, convert your singleton into a legitimate data model, and let your view controller keep a reference to it in a property. Then you can say something like:

```
-(void)myMethod{
    junk = self.model.someValue;
}
```

which is pretty close to what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you're referring to 'legitimate data model' ? Thanks.

Comment: Also, I'm not so much trying to remove the retrieval of the data so much as the redundancy of it in every single method where I need to access/modify any of the values the Singleton contains. Perhaps my question should be "what's the best way to be able to access/modify variables from every Class?" (That may not be right either...)

Comment: By "legitimate data model" I mean not just using the view controller to store your data (as I suggested in the first sentence of that paragraph). It's kind of what you're doing now, but instead of using a globally accessible object, store a pointer to the model in your view controller. With so few objects in your app, it's hard to appreciate the problems that global data can cause, but as your program grows the fact that any code in your app can modify your data will begin to create bugs that are hard to track down. There's much more written on this elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're question is really about (singletons as a common pattern vs common -init method?), but it is common to create what is called a designated initializer for your class. If you're not using a singleton pattern an init method signature that takes a value might look like this:

```
-(id)initWithValue:(NSString*)newValue;
```

As for using a singleton pattern to provide access to your variables I would recommend a more loosely coupled approach, especially if the number of values your singleton class manages begins to grow. I would put those variables into their own classes (separated logically) and use them as needed, by passing them to constructors, or instantiating them. That's an opinion/philosophy issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this to resolve the question.
(Again I was primarily trying to clean out the redundancy of code)
In my Class modules I did the following:

```
#import "GlobalData.h"

GloablData *globDat;

-(id)init{
    if(self=[super init]){
        globDat=[GlobalData getSingleton];
    }
    return self;
}

...

-(void)someMethod{
    int junk=globDat.junkvalue;
}
```