# Memory not releasing when removing object - unclear on proper way to release in ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

Xcode 5, iOS7

I have an app that creates UILabels in a loop, referencing them in an array.
After repeatedly calling the 'creation' method I'm noticing that my memory usage increases.
I'd like to clear the array and the related UILabel objects to free the memory,
as it appears it not happening with my current code. Instead, each time through my loops
I can see my memory usage increasing and never decreasing. I am currently using Storyboards and ARC.

How can I properly release the UILabels since it seems ARC is not doing it for me?

```
@implementation myViewController
CGPoint tmpPoint;
NSMutableArray *allDots;
/// more code here
//
// This method is called repeatedly from another loop
-(void)createLabels{
//remove any previous labels
//I'm pretty sure this is not actually clearing the UILabels but rather the pointer to the labels?
    for(short i=0; i<10; i++){
        UILabel *junkDot=[allDots objectAtIndex:i];
        junkDot=nil;
    }
// Either of these statements should clear the references/pointers
//        [allDots removeAllObjects];
    allDots=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//create a new group of labels
    for(short i=0; i<10; i++){
        // code to generate Point values
        [self makeLabel:tmpPoint];
    }
}

-(UILabel*)makeLabel:(CGPoint)thePoint{
    CGRect xFrame=CGRectMake(thePoint.x, thePoint.y, 40, 20);
    UILabel *tmpLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:xFrame];

    [self.view addSubview:tmpLabel];

    [allDots addObject:tmpLabel];

    return tmpLabel;
}
```

Comment: How do you know memory is not being released? (i.e. how are you measuring memory usage?)

Comment: I noticed after using the app for a while movement became very slow. I then watched the Activity Monitor>Memory as I was running my app from Xcode and it slowly continued to climb, even though it should have been stable (except for the minor up/down as I added/removed objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read up on the basics of memory management.

In ARC, objects are kept in memory as long as there is at least one strong reference to them. As soon as there are no longer any strong references to an object it may be released.

An NSArray (or NSMutableArray) keeps a strong reference to any object that is added to it. If you remove an object from a mutable array (using, e.g. `removeObjectAtIndex:`) the array releases it's strong reference.

Your code that fetches objects from an array and then sets the local variable to nil does absolutely nothing but waste time:

```
for(short i=0; i<10; i++){
    UILabel *junkDot=[allDots objectAtIndex:i];
    junkDot=nil;
}
```

When you add a view object to your view hierarchy using `addSubview:`, the superview also keeps a strong reference to the object.

Thus, if you create a bunch of labels and both put them in an array and add them as subviews of your content view, each label has 2 strong references. A label won't be deallocated until it is both removed from it's superview AND removed from the array.

Comment: 1) Yes, I do need to read up! 2) Will this also release references: allDots=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] instead of looping through removeObjectAtIndex? 3) How do I remove the object(s) from the superview?

Comment: You asked "Will this also release references: allDots=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] instead of looping through removeObjectAtIndex?" Huh?!? Why would you create a new array to release objects from another array? If you have an existing NSMutableArray allDots that contains view objects, you could use removeAllObjects to remove all of the objects in the array at once. But, that brings us to item 3: If you've added views to your view controller's content view, you need to send each view a `removeFromSuperview` message.

Comment: See if you can figure out a loop that would remove all the views in your allDots array from self.view, then remove all the objects from the array once the loop is done. Hint: Look at `for.. in` loop syntax, `removeFromSuperview`, and removeAllObjects.

Comment: Got it - used removeAllObjects and removeFromSuperView and it seems to help. Thanks.

Comment: Good question - I wish people would quit doing that without providing reasons.

Answer (score 2):

```
@implementation myViewController
CGPoint tmpPoint;
NSMutableArray *allDots;
```

Replace Above code with code

```
@implementation myViewController {
CGPoint tmpPoint;
NSMutableArray *allDots;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this would help?

Comment: The above declaration array is global for application.
It will release when app will stop.

And below array declaration in bracket of class implementation is Private object of the class instance. 
So, it will release when super object will get release.

Sorry for I not mention description of my code.

Comment: @wayneh: here your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22640702/3765200 Its saying the declaration of GloablData *globDat; its global for end of the app. And it will release automatically when app terminated.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are keeping the UILabel objects on-screen in the view they should be gone from the array at least with nothing more than the removeAllObjects method. If they aren't, then something else is retaining them.

In your code you are pulling the items from an `allDots` array, but then you are using the `UILabel` still somewhere else. The array has released the object, but since it's still in use somewhere. Since the array only held references, you are just reducing the retain count by 1. The object isn't taking up any more or less memory, it just has one less retain on it.

You can easily set some NSLog or logging breakpoints along the way to see what's happening like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *allDots = [@[] mutableCopy];

    for(NSInteger i=0; i<10; i++){
        UILabel *i = [UILabel new];
        [allDots addObject: i];
    }
    NSLog(@"Contents of array %@", [allDots description]);
    // Either of these statements should clear the references/pointers

    [allDots removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"Contents of array %@", [allDots description]);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

2014-06-29 11:25:59.185 Loper[47174:2208182] Contents of array (
"<UILabel: 0x10b76c370; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b768ef0>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b82b870; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b82b9d0>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b834c10; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b82d510>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b82a9b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b8408b0>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b82ab10; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b834dd0>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b8326e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b837a80>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b832840; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b80ebb0>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b8329a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b841a90>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b846290; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b80eeb0>>",
"<UILabel: 0x10b8465a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x10b846700>>"
)

2014-06-29 11:25:59.185 Loper[47174:2208182] Contents of array (
)
```

To find out what's going on step by step, just throw a regular breakpoint in there and step through the code to see who is holding on to the references.

Other options are to just run the static analyzer and see if any retain loops are detected, or to open your project in Instruments with the leaks or allocation tools and see what's going on under the hood on device.